# Why isn't the fetch API returning a readable stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-blob-storage, fetch-api

I am trying to upload an image from a URL using the fetch API and put it into an Azure container, but I keep getting an error saying I'm not giving it a readable stream. Here is the code:

```
async function test() {
  //fetching an image
  var res = await fetch(
    "...url.png");//fetching an image

  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(res.url);//Creating blob name for azure
  const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(
    res.body,
    res.body._readableState.length,
    { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: "image" } }
  );
  console.log(uploadBlobResponse);
}

test();
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(res.body)`? I.e. done *any* debugging yet?

Comment: Reading [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) indicates you may be doing it wrong

Answer (score 3):

The library you're using is expecting a Node.js Readable stream.

The Fetch api's `Response.prototype.body` returns a `ReadableStream`, a web standard. They're similar in function and name but *not the same*.

In Node 18 there's an experimental [`Readable.fromWeb()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromwebreadablestream-options) that should be able to convert the ReadableStream to an instance of Readable.